# get the remote hostname of a machine on the network using Linux ubuntu with php

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu

i have a web application in  ubuntu + php +apache + mysql ubuntu. This application is redirected by the ip 192.168.0.105. I need to get the ip of my local machines that access this application

for example  I am running this application in the ip 192.168.0.34
i try with

```
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $hostname
```

and my result is 192.168.0.34

[image]

I have other application in windows and 
I don´t have these problems.

i think is linux  , maybe something I set in ubuntu

Can someone help me ?

Comment: what does `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returns ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Looks like it returns `192.168.0.34` which is an internal address and likely doesn't have an associated hostname unless there is an internal network DNS service or `/etc/hosts` entry that assigns one.

Comment: The problem is Linux, because this application in windows the name of machine  appears and for example the name of machine in ubuntu is UBUNTU_DIEGO. i put this sentence for example  echo  gethostname();  and the result is  UBUNTU_DIEGO,

Comment: Do you have your DNS servers set up properly in `/etc/resolv.conf`? Also, is there an entry on in your `/etc/hosts` file on your Windows box for that IP address?